# How to add callback function to a javascript class?

Tags: javascript, oop, class-design, callback

The following code in javascript gives me the error *"this.callback is not a function*

```
function ajaxRequest()
{
    var httpObject;

    this.open = open;
    this.callback = function(){};

    function getHTTPObject()
    {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) 
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        else 
        {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    function onstatechange()
    {
        if(httpObject.readyState == 4)
        {
            this.callback(httpObject.responseText);
        }

    }


    function open(url, callback)
    {
        httpObject = getHTTPObject();
        if (httpObject != null) 
        {
            httpObject.open("GET", url, true);
            httpObject.send(null);
            this.callback = callback;
            httpObject.onreadystatechange = onstatechange;
        }
    }
}
```

why doesn't open method treat the callback parameter as function?

If it does then why can't i call it in onstatechange function?

How do i make this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that because `onstatechange` is being called as an event handler, and the `this` pointer is likely pointing to the object on which the event fired, not the `ajaxRequest` object, as you expect.

The below rewrite stores the `this` variable in a variable called `that` in the execution context to which the onstatechange() function has access.  This ought to cure the problem.

The long and short of all this is if you don't thoroughly understand Javascript closure and execution contexts, and even if you do, you're much, much better off using a framework  to do your AJAX requests.  jQuery and Prototype are good choices.

```
function ajaxRequest()
{
    var httpObject;

    this.open = open;
    this.callback = function(){};
    var that = this;

    function getHTTPObject()
    {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) 
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                return new XMLHttpRequest();
        else 
        {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
                return null;
        }
    }

    function onstatechange()
    {
        if(httpObject.readyState == 4)
        {
                that.callback(httpObject.responseText);
        }

    }


    function open(url, callback)
    {
        httpObject = getHTTPObject();
        if (httpObject != null) 
        {
                httpObject.open("GET", url, true);
                httpObject.send(null);
                this.callback = callback;
                httpObject.onreadystatechange = onstatechange;
        }
    }
}
```