# Is ajax breaking my javascript objects?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I have a page that does ASP.NET ajax postbacks using UpdatePanels.  In some javascript, I set up some objects in the window.onload event, which works great.  When I do a postback though, it seems like my objects are messed up.

One object which was receiving events from a table, is no longer receiving the events.  I also had a case where objects which has local references to buttons wouldn't be able to update them.  Here's the button javascript that was getting messed up:

```
function EditItemPage(clientId)
{
    this.saveButton = $get(clientId + ""_{2}"")
    this.publishButton = $get(clientId + ""_{3}"")
    this.exitButton = $get(clientId + ""_{4}"")

    EditItemPage.prototype.GoDirty = function()
    {
        //it works if i add these, but i'd rather not have to.
        this.saveButton = $get(clientId + ""_{2}"")
        this.publishButton = $get(clientId + ""_{3}"")
        this.exitButton = $get(clientId + ""_{4}"")

        this.saveButton.disabled = false;
        this.publishButton.value = 'Save and Publish';
        this.exitButton.value = 'Discard changes and Exit';
    }
}
```

So after I do a postback, the button references are messed up unless i reset them as I did in the GoDirty() function.

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword (special variable) changes based on what function is calling it. Basically, it's an issue of scope. You need to either do a closure around the function which is being called on the ajax response, *OR* put what you need into the global scope, *OR* do what you are doing (which you don't like).

Writing the closure is the "right" way.

You may be familiar with the way the `this` variable changes scope based on events for form inputs. For a textbox, if you use the onblur event, the `this` refers to the textarea which just lost focus.

[See this question for an example of how to do the closure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456767/how-to-add-callback-function-to-a-javascript-class)

[This is also another good resource.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710542/jquery-javascript-this-pointer-confusion)

(I'm sure I could copy and paste the examples in here for you, but that seems redundant)